# How can I decorate my enum when using FunctionalAPI?

Tags: python, enums, decorator

```
from enum import IntEnum, unique

# @unique <- decorator syntax does not work for variable assignment
Weekday = IntEnum("Weekday", "sun mon tue wed thu fri sat", start=0)
```

Obviously one could just write this out as a class but I wonder if this is possible with the syntax as shown above.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it as a function instead of a decorator.

```
Weekday = unique(IntEnum("Weekday", "sun mon tue wed thu fri sat", start=0))
```

However, it's not necessary:  the use of Functional API guarantees that every value will be unique. This is done in `_generate_next_value_` in [enum.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/enum.py).

Creating `IntEnum` invokes `__call__`

```
def __call__(cls, value, names=None, *, ..., start=1):
```

which invokes `cls._create_`

```
def _create_(cls, class_name, names, *, ..., start=1):
```

which calls `_generate_next_value_` in a loop to assign values in increasing order

```
for count, name in enumerate(original_names):
    first_enum._generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values[:])
```